# SQL query - How to show when data repeats itself for x number of entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard and I still very new to SQL Server.

I am trying to find when a x (measurement) has trend data that flatlines for longer than 48 intervals of the date time.

Thanks in advance.

My base query structure is

```
SELECT sites.site_name, 
       measurements.measurement_name, 
       trend_data_temp.trend_data_avg, 
       trend_data_temp.trend_data_time 
FROM   sites 
       INNER JOIN group_sites 
               ON sites.site_id = group_sites.site_id 
       INNER JOIN groups 
               ON group_sites.group_id = groups.group_id 
       INNER JOIN measurements 
               ON sites.site_id = measurements.site_id 
       INNER JOIN trend_data 
               ON measurements.measurement_id = trend_data.measurement_id 
       INNER JOIN trend_data_temp 
               ON measurements.measurement_id = trend_data_temp.measurement_id 
GROUP  BY sites.site_name, 
          measurements.measurement_name, 
          trend_data_temp.trend_data_avg, 
          trend_data_temp.trend_data_time 
ORDER  BY sites.site_name, 
          measurements.measurement_name
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of data that should be returned by this query, and data that would not?

Comment: So in other words, 48 rows in a row in `trend_data_temp` should have identical values for `trend_data_avg`?

Comment: Basicly I am wanting to show the measure if 'Raw Velocity' measurement name stays the same value or below a known value for a specific amount of time. The output of is as follows.

Comment: site_name measurement_name trend_data_time trend_data_avg
HI-1 Raw Velocity 10/1/09 10:20 5.644379
HI-1 Raw Velocity 10/1/09 10:25 5.570816
HI-1 Raw Velocity 10/1/09 10:30 5.561096
HI-1 Raw Velocity 10/1/09 10:35 5.5079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slightly in the dark without any outlines of input data and output data but maybe you need something like this (not tested)

```
   SELECT 
           sites.site_name, 
           measurements.measurement_name, 
           trend_data_temp.trend_data_avg, 
           [occurances] = count(trend_data_temp.trend_data_time) 
    FROM   sites 
           INNER JOIN group_sites 
                   ON sites.site_id = group_sites.site_id 
           INNER JOIN groups 
                   ON group_sites.group_id = groups.group_id 
           INNER JOIN measurements 
                   ON sites.site_id = measurements.site_id 
           INNER JOIN trend_data 
                   ON measurements.measurement_id = trend_data.measurement_id 
           INNER JOIN trend_data_temp 
                   ON measurements.measurement_id = trend_data_temp.measurement_id 
    GROUP  BY 
           sites.site_name, 
           measurements.measurement_name, 
           trend_data_temp.trend_data_avg
    HAVING count(trend_data_temp.trend_data_time) >=48
```